# site only shows all info from index.php?

Tags: php, html, web

Sorry if this is a basic question, but Im wondering why my site doesn't display correctly unless I utilize the index.php extension. Here is an example :

www.copishboutqiue.com/salon

which displays incorrectly but

www.copishboutique.com/salon/index.php displays the correct layout we're using. Why do I need to use the index.php when this is the only file in the root directory?

Comment: check your domain name spell.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an apache server create a .htaccess file in the root directory of your website and add

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```